# How to length the last dimension of a numpy array and fill it up with another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array of shape `(5, 4, 3)` and another numpy array of shape `(4,)` and what I want to do is expand the last dimension of the first array
`(5, 4, 3) -> (5, 4, 4)`
and then broadcast the other array with shape `(4,)` such that it fills up the new array cells respectively.

Example:

```
np.ones((5,4,3))
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

becomes

```
array([[[1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0.]]])
```

And then I have another array

```
array([2., 3., 4., 5.])
```

which I somehow broadcast with the first one to fill the zeros:

```
array([[[1., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4.],
        [1., 1., 1., 5.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4.],
        [1., 1., 1., 5.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4.],
        [1., 1., 1., 5.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4.],
        [1., 1., 1., 5.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4.],
        [1., 1., 1., 5.]]])
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) and [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
A = np.ones((5,4,3), dtype='int')
B = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])

np.c_[A, np.tile(B[:,None], (A.shape[0], 1, 1))]
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 4],
        [1, 1, 1, 5]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 4],
        [1, 1, 1, 5]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 4],
        [1, 1, 1, 5]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 4],
        [1, 1, 1, 5]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 4],
        [1, 1, 1, 5]]])
```

How it works:

```
# reshape B to add one dimension
>>> B[:, None]
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])

# tile to match A's first dimension
>>> np.tile(B[:,None], (A.shape[0], 1, 1))
array([[[2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]],

       [[2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]],

       [[2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]],

       [[2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]],

       [[2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of doing this, but one of simplest is to make a array of the desired final size, and fill in the values.

I could start with a `np.zeros((5,4,4))`, and insert the `np.ones((5,4,3))`, but why not just start with all ones:

```
In [680]: res = np.ones((5,4,4))
```

The we can easily copy the 4 element list/array to the last column with:

```
In [681]: res[:,:,-1] = [2,3,4,5]
In [682]: res
Out[682]: 
array([[[1., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4.],
        [1., 1., 1., 5.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 4.],
        [1., 1., 1., 5.]],
       ...
```

The (4,) shape array is `broadcasted` to (1,4), which easily fits in  `(5,4)` slot defined by `res[:,:,-1]`.

Expanding the (4,) to (5,4,1) (with `tile`), and then concatenating that with the (5,4,3) also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.append](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_append.htm) :

```
A=np.ones((5,4,3))
AA=np.zeros((5,4,1))
B=np.array([2., 3., 4., 5.])
C=np.append(A,AA, axis=2)
for i in range(np.shape(C)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(C)[1]):
            C[i,j,-1]=B[j]
print(C)

> 
[[[1. 1. 1. 2.]
  [1. 1. 1. 3.]
  [1. 1. 1. 4.]
  [1. 1. 1. 5.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 2.]
  [1. 1. 1. 3.]
  [1. 1. 1. 4.]
  [1. 1. 1. 5.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 2.]
  [1. 1. 1. 3.]
  [1. 1. 1. 4.]
  [1. 1. 1. 5.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 2.]
  [1. 1. 1. 3.]
  [1. 1. 1. 4.]
  [1. 1. 1. 5.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 2.]
  [1. 1. 1. 3.]
  [1. 1. 1. 4.]
  [1. 1. 1. 5.]]]
```

Comment: You should really not use loops with numpy

Comment: Taking advantage of `broadcasting` you can skip the loop, and just assign `B` to the last column of `C`.  `C[:,:-1] = B`.